# The name 'x' does not exist in the current context in master page Page_Load?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, master-pages

In my `default.aspx.cs`, I get the following error:

`The name 'LocaleConverter' does not exist in the current context`

I get the error on this line in `Page_Load`:

```
httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
```

The error happens when I add the following to a master page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Fingerprint.Tag("~/Scripts/LocaleConverter.js")%>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Fingerprint.Tag("~/Scripts/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-" + LocaleConverter.convertLocale("fr-FR") + ".js")%>"></script>
```

This is `LocaleConverter`:

```
var LocaleConverter = (function() {

    return {
        convertLocale: function(localeToConvert) {
            switch (localeToConvert) {
                case 'en-US':
                    return 'en-US';
                case 'en-GB':
                    return 'en-GB';
                case 'es':
                case 'es-MX':
                    return 'es';
                case 'fr-FR':
                    return 'fr';
                case 'fr-CH':
                    return 'fr-CH';
                default:
                    return 'en-US';
            }
        }
    }

} (LocaleConverter));
```

Comment: What is `LocaleConverter`? Is it your custom class? If so, where is it declared?

Comment: Just add a `using` directive with the namespace of your `LocaleConverter` class ...

Comment: @Andrei - LocaleConverter is a javascript file.  Post updated with LocaleConverter code.

Comment: If iLocaleConverter is a js file, you are using it wrong. You call it from the code behind inside the `<% %>` tags ...

Comment: Compiler is expecting `LocaleConverter.convertLocale("fr-FR")` to be C# code, not javascript

Comment: @SmartDev - The only place I am calling it is in my MasterPage like this:  `<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Fingerprint.Tag("~/Scripts/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-" + LocaleConverter.convertLocale("fr-FR") + ".js")%>"></script>`

Comment: Exactly! You are concatenating these `"~/Scripts/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-" + LocaleConverter.convertLocale("fr-FR") + ".js"` in C#. And `LocaleConverter.convertLocale("fr-FR")` is not defined in C#.

Comment: @SmartDev - Sorry, a bit confused, convertLocale should just return a string, so I want it to concatenate. Am I missing some character?  And it is just a javascript function.

Comment: What's inside `<%=   %>` is C# code. It doesn't matter that you have javascript function, you need C# function here

Comment: @dotnetom - Ah, I get what you are saying.  It all makes sense now.  So is there anyway to still use my javascript function and concatenate the result?